# How to properly fscanf txt file in C

Tags: c, file, scanf

For example: #1 Tutti/Leeloo/853811356; N

And this is my code:

```
typedef struct{
    int redni;
    char prezime[50+1];
    char ime[50+1];
    char osobna[50+1];
    char glasao[10];

} Biraliste;


int nBiraci=0;

while(fscanf(biralisteTxt,  "%d %[^/]/%[^/]/%[^;];%[^\n]",
             biraci[n].redni, biraci[n].prezime, biraci[n].ime, biraci[n].osobna, biraci[n].glasao  ) == 5)
{
    nBiraci++;

}

for(i=0;i<nBiraci;i++)
{

        fprintf(statistikaTxt, "%d %s %s %s %s", 
&biraci[i].redni, biraci[i].prezime, biraci[i].ime, biraci[i].osobna, biraci[i].glasao );


}
```

Can someone help mi with right fscanf and fprintf, and is it ok to fscanf redni with %d or it should be %s.

Comment: Well, for starters, `biraci[n].redni` as the first argument is wrong. It should be `&biraci[n].redni` . That, assuming `n` is really somewhere in the *real* code, which should have been posted in the first place. I'm pressed to see how you're skipping that leading `#` regardless, but that's another matter, I suspect.

Comment: `redni` is `int` type so it must be `%d`. `%s` is for `char *`

Comment: Well, for starters, [don't do this with `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf).  The \*scanf family of functions are broken-as-specified and should never be used for _anything_; in this case, the most important reason why they're not fit for purpose is that they don't respect the size limits on the fields of `Biraliste`.

Comment: I fixed &biraci[n].redni . But how should I scanf it

Comment: nBiraci is my counter @WhozCraig

Comment: Or i should count number of lines first ?

Comment: I suggest to read an input line with `fgets`, use `strtok` or `strchr` to separate the fields. Then you can handle your string fields with `str*`functions and numbers with `strtol` or similar.

Comment: No, I need only a number

Comment: int p=0;

    while(fscanf(biralisteTxt,  "%c %d %[^/]/%[^/]/%[^;];%[^\n]",

                 biraci[p].hash,&biraci[p].redni, biraci[p].prezime, biraci[p].ime, 

biraci[p].osobna, biraci[p].glasao  ) == 5)

    {
        p++;

    }

Comment: There is an & too much in front of `&biraci[i].redni` in the second loop.

Answer (score 2):

" #%d %[^/]/%[^/]/%[^;];%[^\n]" - this is the right answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following code fixes two problems.

- scanf must get the address of the variable to fill, this `&biraci...`
- the index must be `nBiraci` and not `n`, thus `&biraci[nBiraci]...`
- there must be a # in front of %d

```c
int nBiraci=0;
while(fscanf(biralisteTxt,  " #%d %[^/]/%[^/]/%[^;];%[^\n]",
             &biraci[nBiraci].redni, (char*)&biraci[nBiraci].prezime,
             (char*)&biraci[nBiraci].ime, (char*)&biraci[nBiraci].osobna,
             (char*)&biraci[nBiraci].glasao) == 5)
{
    nBiraci++;
}
```

Comment: It still says that counter is 0, maybe i should include 
char hash?

Comment: @IOVOR you are right. I missed that error. I updated my answer.

Comment: @user3121023 you are right as well. I updated the answer.